# How to make invalid server response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I am using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and PHP for uploading files.

But the documentation of Dropzone lacks of saying how to tell Dropzone the file upload failed.
Understand, that I want to validate the files server-side too,

so I need a way how to tell Dropzone it is not ok...

Does anyone know how? - Should I send some error header?

Comment: the server should return a HTTP code (200 - ok or some other code for error or timeout) and you should catch that error and inform the user about the issue, i'm thinking of javascript callbacks ...

Comment: Pretty same idea as "cristi _b", proceed the file upload by AJAX and use the onComplete feature to retrieve the result of the operation.

Comment: I think I was not clear enaugh :D - I am using Dropzone so I dont have to make the ajax sending by myself, onComplete is of course solution if it would be just my code :) ... But what is the "onComplete" in Dropzone? "complete" method of Dropzone? **Anyway I still need to pass that response to the method that indicates graphicly whether the file was uploaded or not...**

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this in your php code:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
```

Dropzone will then mark the file with a red cross (given that the spritemap is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

I accidentaly found a solution.

It is a combination of both header() && text,

If you put error header in PHP the Dropzone.js takes show the "graphic" error sign acordingly-

The message displayed on :hover on the thumbnail is the server responseText.

So the solution could be:

```
  if( $file_save_error ){
    header(':', true, 405); //send error header, I chose "405 Method Not Allowed"
    echo "Soubor se nepodařilo uložit"; //give proper info to user
  }
```